# my CSS bugged, i want a white line box with 4 pictures on the left and text on the right

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: black;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    
}

body p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.img-wrap{
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


.box {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.container-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px;
}

.text-box {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}



header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}

header .logo {
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.top{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    z-index: 5000;
}

.left{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    writing-mode: sideways-lr;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;


}

.bottom{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Aylin Hyusmen's Portfolio</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/aylin-hyusmen-b272b3229/" class="logo">Contact</a>
    </header>
<a class="top" href="index.html">01. Home</a>
<a class="right" href="about.html">02. About</a>
<a class="left" href="projects.html">03. Resume</a>
 <a  class="bottom" href="./cv.txt">04. Download CV</a>
 <div class="box">
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="section">
     <div class="container"></div>
     <div class="container-row"> <img class="img-wrap" src="/folder/images/first.jpg" alt="First Headshot"> </div> </div>
     <div> <img class="img-wrap" src="/folder/images/second.jpg" alt="Second Headshot"> </div> </div>
     <div class="container-row"> <img class="img-wrap" src="/folder/images/third.jpeg" alt="Third Headshot"> </div> </div>
     <div> <img class="img-wrap" src="/folder/images/fourth.jpg"  alt="Fourth Headshot"> </div> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <h1>Aylin Hyusmen, 1997</h1>
    <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

I cannot seem to make this possible,  I want to fill with the four pictures and the text on the right side, i do not want the page to scroll up and down i just wnat a good box in the middle with white text. I want the white line box to be laying down, not vertical too and I tried everything but my images do not load i only see the alternative texts and i do not know why. sorry if its obvious i am new to this.

Comment: Have you checked via your browser's dev tools inspect facility whether those images are being loaded? My suspicion is that the path is wrong, but of course I have no way of checking. Also, if you could include a rough picture of what the final layout is to be I think that would help.

Comment: Yes, I will try to detail it. https://imgur.com/a/WNZ3NWO - This is how I want the page to look in the end, if you would like to invest more time in it my discord is Heartfilia#2107 sooooo I would be really thankful if you give me a call and explain ot to me

Comment: From your picture I think it is worth your investigating CSS grid. However, first you need to find why those imgs don’t load. What does your browser console tell you?

Comment: just says could not load image

Comment: Does it not give a reason or an error code? Try putting in the complete URL.

Comment: well I am trying to make the css grid but it doesnt workout im using like the generators to play around but i cannot seem to get it the way I want, and the pictures are not urls they are photos on my pc and i use VSC so it would be really hard to get the path wrong

Comment: OK, if the images are local can you show us your folder structure - where exactly are they? Where is the folder called folder?

Comment: <div class="pictures-row"> <img src="/images/first.jpg"> <img src="/images/second.jpg"> </div>
it's in home/desktop/portfolio/images

Comment: Sorry, that is not the folder structure on your computer. It’s the folder structure you need to look at to check where everything is.